# How do I extract just the title and artist?

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am trying to extract all the titles and artist. I can currently get the JSON page with all the entries, but having trouble extracting the title and artist only. Below is the code to get to the page.

[image]

```
 func getMeta(){

    let searchTerm = PFUser.currentUser?.username
    var endpoint = NSURL(string: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=\(searchTerm)&api_key=aa03f5bd00409f3bb5372c6ad0bc5655&format=json&callback=?")
    var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: endpoint!)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(endpoint!) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let dict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            {
              if let items = dict["track"] as? NSArray {
                    for item in items {
                        let x =  (dict["track"]!["name"] as? String)!
                        print(x)
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch let jsonError as NSError {
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Research about Alamofire & SwiftyJSON. Simple

Comment: I did, that's how I got this far. I'm still not familiar with it. I'm just trying to figure out how to get just the title and artist for each entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never ignore error messages.

Add `print(jsonError)` inside the `catch` branch and you will see the error: your JSON is not valid.

Why? Because in your URL you're using `callback` which adds JavaScript characters in front of the JSON string.

Remove `&callback=?` from the URL, the URL should just end with `&format=json`.

Then you have to correctly follow the JSON types: what is a dictionary, what is an array, what are the keys... and safely unwrap the values with `if let` or any other known method:

```
do {
    if let jsonData = data,
        let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as? NSDictionary,
        let recent = dict["recenttracks"] as? NSDictionary,
        let items = recent["track"] as? NSArray {
            for item in items {
                if let x = item["name"] as? String {
                    print(x)
                }
            }
    }
} catch let jsonError as NSError {
    print(jsonError)
}
```

Comment: I get this error `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Comment: I explain in my answer how to modify the URL to be able to get the right JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just try Alamofire?

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseJSON { response in
             print(response.request)  // original URL request
             print(response.response) // URL response
             print(response.data)     // server data
             print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

             if let JSON = response.result.value {
                 print("JSON: \(JSON)")
             }
         }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Alamofire and I feel more comfortable using my approach.